# Unity C# scriptable object with an instance of a serializable scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am hoping to make a scriptable object that has an array of serializable scriptable objects in it. This would allow me to add references from other scriptable objects onto it within the Unity inspector.

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class BehaviourSO : ScriptableObject {
    public string Name = "New Behaviour";
    public BehaviourSO[] TransitionalBehaviour = new BehaviourSO[1];

    public abstract BehaviourAI Initialize();
}
```

Is this possible? If not, what would be a nice alternative to this.

[The inspector view of the scriptable object want the array to be in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0FYL.png)

The scriptable object in this picture inherits from the BehaviourSO class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for my question.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AttackAI : BehaviourAI
{
}
```

I needed to add system.serializable on my scriptable objects that inherited from the BehaviorSO class.